# Show mutiple v-dialog boxes with different content in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Hii I am working on the Vue.js template and I stuck at a point where I need to show dynamic v-dialog using looping statement but now it shows all.

Dom:

```
<template v-for="item of faq">
    <div :key="item.category">
       <h4>{{ item.heading }}</h4>
       <div v-for="subitems of item.content" :key="subitems.qus">
          <v-dialog
             v-model="dialog"
             width="500"
          >
             <template v-slot:activator="{on}">
                <a href="#" v-on="on">{{subitems.qus}}</a>
             </template>
             <v-card>
                <v-card-title
                   class="headline grey lighten-2"
                   primary-title
                   >
                   Privacy Policy
                </v-card-title>
                <v-card-text>
                   {{ subitems.ans }}
                </v-card-text>
                <v-divider></v-divider>
             </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
       </div>
    </div>
 </template>
```

Script:

```
export default {
      data: () => ({
         faq,
         dialog:false,
      }),
   }
```

I do not understand how I can do this. If I click on one button then it shows all.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output? You bind the model of the dialogs to the same variable, and you do not want to show up all at once?

Answer (score 6):

There must a design a pattern for this one but a quick solution would be to create array of booleans for v-models of dialogs. something like below

```
export default {
      data: () => ({
         faq,
         dialog: [] // Array instead of Boolean.
      }),
   }
```

and

```
<template v-for="item of faq">
    <div :key="item.category">
       <h4>{{ item.heading }}</h4>
       <div v-for="(subitems, index) of item.content" :key="subitems.qus">
          <v-dialog
             v-model="dialog[index]"
             width="500"
          >
             <template v-slot:activator="{on}">
                <a href="#" v-on="on">{{subitems.qus}}</a>
             </template>
             <v-card>
                <v-card-title
                   class="headline grey lighten-2"
                   primary-title
                   >
                   Privacy Policy
                </v-card-title>
                <v-card-text>
                   {{ subitems.ans }}
                </v-card-text>
                <v-divider></v-divider>
             </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
       </div>
    </div>
 </template>
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply but it is still showing all popup not show single popup on click of the specific button.

Comment: Hi @VarinderSohal, can you show the code of that specific button on which you want to show the popup please?

Comment: Great, you can answer your own question here, maybe it'll help someone else

Answer (score 1):

Brother, you are doing a very small mistake, you should not keep your v-dialog component inside your loop, take this out from loop block and don't take dialog as empty array keep it false.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to loop over the v-dialog your v-model value need to be an array of booleans where you pass the index in like this v-model ="arrayOfBoolean[i]". then simple create two function to open and close based on the index value. to open you set the selected index to true and to close false. hope this helps.